# What is a SwiftShims module?

Tags: swift2, xcode7-beta4

I'm attempting to transform a Swift v1.2 project into a Swift v2.0 project via Xcode 7.0.

I got this during the build:

> Swift had fatal errors constructing the ast context for this module:
>   missing required module 'SwiftShims' Debug info from this module will
>   be unavailable in the debugger.

What is the module 'SwiftShims'?  
And how would I install it if it is missing?

Answer (score 5):

I was getting a similar error message regarding the **SwiftShims** module, so this is probably only a partial solution to your case.

I had to clean all the user data Xcode was using and empty all caches. This did the job for me:

[How to Empty Caches and Clean All Targets Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4/6247073#6247073)